# How can I avoid printing repeated data from database to a label using C#

Tags: c#, database, printing, repeat

I am creating an assessment portal in C#, I have a database containing 50 questions, I want to print it randomly without repeating the questions. Am able to print the questions randomly, but it is repeating sometimes. Please help me to avoid this issue.

Comment: What exactly are you doing. At least show your code here. You can use datalist also for achieving same.

Comment: You can add random question id in some collection and use that collection to avoid the repetition of same question using method like Contains before adding new question

Comment: You can use a collection type like HashSet<T> that removes duplicates by default, and use a random whose bounds are the length of the set to pick a question from the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the questions in random order and only print of you need, filtering in the code behind

For get the random Question only must add `order statment` with `NEWID()` function

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Questions(
question     VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #questions
VALUES 
    ('A'),
    ('B'),
    ('C'),
    ('D'),
    ('E'),
    ('F'),

SELECT 
    QUESTION 
FROM #QUESTION
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

If you want to obtain only the necessary, you can add a `top statment` to the query

Example:

```
SELECT TOP 3
QUESTION 
FROM #QUESTION
ORDER BY NEWID()
```